# Help with a pointer

Tags: hex, hexadecimal, cheat-engine

Sorry for this stupid question. It's late here and I've been kinda stuck for a while over this so I hope someone here can answer this easily.

In CheatEngine, 028FA190+374 is pointing to 028F1788. When I type in 028FA190+374 in the calculator I get 28FA504. Can someone explain me why this is different?

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Answer (score 4):

It's different, because it isn't just `0x28FA190 + 0x374`, but it's `*(0x28FA190 + 0x374)`.

`0x28FA190` is a base address, probably of a structure, and `0x374` is an offset, when you sum these values and dereference the result, you get value of a field that's `0x374` bytes away from the beginning of this structure. This field seems to be a pointer, that's why it's value is also an address, but it could contain any value.

```
struct A
{
  char padding[0x374]; // occupy the first 0x374 bytes, so that myPointer's address is address of this structure + 0x374 (i.e. (DWORD)this + 0x374)

  int* myPointer;
};

A a;

int valueOfMyPointer = **(int**)((DWORD)&a + 0x374); // valueOfMyPointer = *a.myPointer;
```

You need to explicitly cast `&a` to `DWORD` (aka `unsigned long`), because of pointer arithmetic - if you would do `&a + 0x374`, the result would actually be `(DWORD)&a + 0x374 * sizeof(a)`.

You can also write the entire expression from your screen as following:

`uint32_t result = *(DWORD*)(*(DWORD*)((DWORD)GetModuleHandle("ac_client.exe") + 0x374) + 0x14);`